# how to update multiple items to table with one particular receipt no using ASP.Net C# and MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables `itemTbl` and `receiptTbl` as follows:

`itemTbl` (where I store the item details)

```
itemId |  itemName  |  itemPrice |
01        Item1         $10
02        Item2         $5
03        Item3         $6
```

And another table `receiptTbl` (where I store the purchase details by customer)

```
receiptId | customerId  |  itemId    |   itemQuanty  | itemTprice  | date
001          C001           01           2              $20          25-07-2014
001          C001           02           1              $5           25-07-2014
002          C002           01           3              $30          25-07-2014
003          C001           02           4              $20          26-07-2014
003          C001           01           4              $40          26-07-2014
003          C001           03           1              $6           26-07-2014
```

I'm trying to find the solution that I'm able to retrieve the values to the page like `CustomerId` and Item details.

I'm looking for some example where and how to insert multiple item details with one receipt ID generating to all the item purchased with a button click and store the values in table.

Comment: What did you try, with what exactly are you having problems?

Comment: i have page receipt.aspx and i m able to insert with one row but i m not getting how to program to insert multiple row with a submit button click.

Comment: i want to update the table with the purchase details and purchase detail means it has only one receiptId per purchase with many items as in above table  receiptTbl. @MarkRotteveel i m looking for some example with code sample with ASP.net and MS SQL 2008. thanks in advance.